# Moving multipoint using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, multipoint

I am trying to move a multipoint object using the edit toolbar, but I keep getting the below error:

```
> Uncaught Error: [esri.toolbars.Edit::activate] Unable to activate the
> tool. Check if the tool is valid for the given geometry type.
```

I have read that using `editToolbar.activate(Edit.MOVE, selected);` is not possible for multipoint geometries. Is there any other way to do this? I am trying to move all the points at the same time not one at a time, this I can achieve using the following : `editToolbar.activate(Edit.EDIT_VERTICES, selected);`

I am using  ArcGIS JS API (v3.22)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue with this question, I have represented the error and the problem as well as the desired outcome.

Comment: You seem to be presenting less than a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck but, I am not a JavaScript developer so I'll re-open in case I'm wrong.